# How to use USB to communicate PC with a USB device?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, digital-communications, usb-host

As I stated above I need to learn to create a healthy communication pathway between a PC and a USB device.

I need to achieve 120MBytes/s(at least)  baud-rate and I don't even have any idea about what kind of board should I use to achieve that.

I've been told that with Cypress FX3 Ez USB board I can arrange the device sided installations easily, but what about the PC side?

Do I have to write some protocol programs to use USB port as a COM port in a desired format? If yes, how to achieve that? Some say that I can do it via libusb on some linux. But I have no experience in such things so these don't mean much to me in practical-sense.

I need a beacon light, a guide, a something to dig further. I couldn't find anything on the net much.

What IDE should I use? What kind of hardware do I need? Any additional software should I use? Any advices so far? A book? Some project examples & application notes; example codes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to write something that receives packets from USB. It's not that hard, I pointed to example hardware in your last question that comes with an open source driver, so copy as much as you want of that! In essence, your devices sends bulk data, and you just use libusb to receive that. Really no big deal. Get an eval board and start hacking, is what I'd recommend.

Comment: http://www.cypress.com/products/ez-usb-fx3-superspeed-usb-30-peripheral-controller

Comment: I was confused and I started to feel that I was exceeding the boundaries of that question so I wanted to ask a new question based on this. I was unavailable to comprehend back then, but I guess I can understand what you are saying now. I'll order a board asap then get my hands in mud, transform that code into my stuff. Thanks again and again.

Comment: really, read the system level "collateral guide" they recommend there first. Maybe https://github.com/cnlohr/fx3fun is an inspiration to you, too!

Comment: This github profile will really help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, you must be joking, right? The question is "... but what about the PC side?"

Comment: @AliChen actually, I'm not joking! My experience is that once you've gotten to the point where your firmware answers with BULK packets, the rest really is basic libusb handling, no actual device driver necessary (source: that's how Ettus presses up to 80MS/s complex int16 through USB3 into normal PCs). Questions like "how to write software that's efficiently handling that amount of data", I'd argue, are out of scope here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After cross-examining of posts from OP on other sites as suggested by Marcus Mueller, the original problem is now become apparent as X-Y problem. The OP is tasked for a college project to build a data acquisition system for some sort of spectrum analyzer for 40MHz-wide signal. They elected to sample the signal at 120 Msamples/s with 12 bit ADC, and send this raw data stream to a modern PC for processing. It is not clear whether the problem requires real-time processing, or block-processing can be fine. In any case the data acquisition system will produce a data stream of 200 Mbytes/s. This is a challenging problem for regular PC, to handle this king of data rate. It is obvious that this kind of bandwidth can't be managed by archaic interfaces as "COM port".

Other than barely manageable interfaces as direct PCIe extender or something like Thunderbolt or 10GB Ethernet, the standard USB 3.0 port should be capable to handle 200 MB/s stream. For example, Cypress EZ-USB FX3 peripheral [controller was reported](http://www.cypress.com/file/125281/download) to achieve about 450 MB/s bulk transfer rate on USB 3.0 generic interface. The Cypress offers full development platform for the device side, and PC host driver with application examples. An alternative could be the [FTDI FT600/601 bridge](http://www.cypress.com/documentation/application-notes/an87216-designing-gpif-ii-master-interface).

Therefore I would suggest the following hardware architecture for the project, based on Cypress as an example. A 12-bit ADC should be managed by a small FPGA, which provides the [Cypress Master FIFO interface](http://www.cypress.com/documentation/application-notes/an87216-designing-gpif-ii-master-interface) in addition to controlling ADC and store data into ping-pong buffer. The FPGA manages [Cypress slave FIFO interface](http://www.cypress.com/documentation/application-notes/an65974-designing-ez-usb-fx3-slave-fifo-interface), and FX3 bridges the data stream into USB 3.0 interface.

The host side uses standard xHCI USB 3.0 controller with default OS software stack, and uses the Cypress driver to provide the link to application level.

The application should likely have a ping-pong receive buffer, and forward the data for processing, Fourier Transform, or whatever. It isn't clear if current PCs can perform Fourier processing in real time, so the processing might be resorted to one data block at a time, with post processing creating gaps in the stream of data.

In my professional opinion, at the target data rate, this project will need professional development of muli-layer PCB with ADC, FPGA, and FX3 chips in a chain, and a serious software effort to optimize/configure host software to achieve 200 Msps processing rate. I will restrain myself from commenting on amout of engineering time this project will take.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer mister! I hope we can (I work with a partner) finish the sampling & processing side of the project in one or two months, test & optimize it and finally start the development of the RF front-end side. I think there's not much left in my mind to be enlightened. Have a nice day!

Comment: Um, really, there's room-full-of-experienced-engineer-years going into the development of SDRs that do exactly what you seem to need, and that is **not** involving the time it takes the customers of these engineers to write software that can do useful stuff with 200MS/s, as Ali Chen tried to point out. What you describe is not "done with sampling and processing in one or two months". Think "in 2 monts, we'll have a prototype that almost reliably spits out samples generated in the FPGA, in the quarter after that we're doing the ADC communication and analog design", not "all in 1 to 2 months"!

Comment: So, the questions you asked so far really are what I'd consider the "easiest" part, as for those, there's dedicated, ready to use hard- and software that comes with extensive tooling and documentation. The rest is all something that you need to develop. On your own. Seriously. I've pointed you to commercial SDRs, and to their schematics. Look at these schematics. How much time, experience, prototype revisions, measuring and re-doing do you think goes into that? And you mention "RF", and that implies that the schematic only gives you but a glimpse of the analog problems you'll be having...

Comment: For the RF-analog section, we will be doing fine; we have some experienced assistants and a professor that will help out us. The biggest problem is the communication handling. If there's no way to manage to build the partition that we've been talking about until now in the time interval of 2 months (max), I can't graduate. It doesn't have to be perfect. Would you suggest anything else, maybe lowering the bandwidth of the original signal by some value?

Comment: @Mynameisname, in your situation, if you want at accomplish data acquisition in 40 MHz range in 2 month, the only way would be to go with known solution called "PC scope", and modify display software. For a 50MHz PicoScope, their Series3000 goes for $579, https://www.picotech.com/oscilloscope/3000/usb3-oscilloscope-logic-analyzer You might find less expensive devices if block-by-block data capture is okay, https://www.sainsmart.com/products/dds-120-pc-based-virtual-oscilloscope-silver or http://bitscope.com/product/BS05/ if 20MHz is enough.

Comment: In 2 month, you will **not** do something great, and only "usable at all" with more contribution from someone experienced than from yourself with your level of expertise, and you can't really claim "you've done that", if the others do that. I fully second what @AliChen says: when you need a measurement device, then buy a measurement device, you will save a) a lot of money, b) a lot of time and c) a lot of wrong results and irritation. If you need a software defined radio receiver, by an SDR device. Don't reinvent the wheel if you're not a wheelwright.

Comment: and with "analog" I didn't mean the input side of that ADC, but simply the physical aspect of the communication between ADC, FPGA, and FX3. You really don't even have a rough idea about the problems you will encounter – and there's simply no way you'll learn all that in 2 months *and* solve the problems *and* develop anything that works *and* calibrate *and* improve your prototypes to a state where you can actually make sensible measurements. Talk to your professor and get a clearer idea of the scope. Say hello, "the internet" says this isn't feasible for an inexperienced student in 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been told that with Cypress FX3 Ez USB board I can arrange the
>   device sided installations easily, but what about the PC side? ...
>   What IDE should I use? What kind of hardware do I need? Any additional
>   software should I use?

Apparently you are missing quite a few system layers of USB framework. To begin, USB is a complex protocol involving complicated serial interface engine, packet, etc. The FX3 is at device end of this link, and provides all low-level protocol services.

On the host (PC) side of a USB link there is always a very complicated USB controller, a hardware that generates all this tokens, requests, transactions, and analyses bus responses.  It is called EHCI or xHCI - "enhanced" or "extended" Host Controller Interface.

This host interface is managed by a sizable software driver, which provides all transaction control and USB port connect/disconnect management. And when a USB device is connected to a port, the host system loads additional piece of software called "device driver".

Now, all USB devices are arranged into device classes, each class has a pre-defined interface. It is done to simplify transport levels of communication protocol, so some universal class-agnostic drivers can be used, all written by software professionals, for easy to use at application level.

For example, if a USB device (say, based on FX chip) is configured as "comminication class", the system will load "COM" driver, and the device will appear as "COM" port with some number, so applications as terminals can communicate in a standard way.

In short, there is a long way from your original point. You might want to start with "[USB in a NutShell](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml)".

Comment: well, but from his application description, OP really just needs the ability to access BULK packets, and there's a hostside driver for that already in Linux/BSDs (and available for Windows etc), and the userland end of that is libusb. So, I don't really think there's a lot of "low level handling" to be considered here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, the OP asks, "What kind of hardware do I need?", "on PC side", in order "to use USB port as a COM port".  This kind of phraseology suggests total misunderstanding of USB. I was addressing this obvious and very deep gap. Do you have a different interpretation of the question?

Comment: My Interpretation is based on the impression that op wants to know what kind of hardware *interfacing* he needs. Compare his question on dsp.SE!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, your interpretation is not supported by the original text. The text says that FX-whatever is the hardware interface that *"I[OP] can arrange the device sided installations easily"*, and explicitly asks, *"but what about the PC side?"*. This leaves only one interpretation, mine :-)

Comment: I don't agree, but that doesn't hurt - your answer is fine for your interpretation! I really don't know who down voted it, it wasn't me.

Comment: All of these answers... were just... great. Every single sentence created by both Mr. Müller and Mr. Chen clarified something else in my mind for both questions I've asked so far. If I had enough reputation I'd upvote all the answers but unfortunately I have not. And I don't know why on earth would a person downvote an answer like this. I am really happy that I've asked the questions in aforementioned sites and coincided with you two & your answers, thanks so much. (I want @MarcusMüller to be notified by this comment too.)